# JUnit forRest API with File Uploader fails with 406 Error

Tags: java, spring, rest, junit, spring-restcontroller

I have RestAPI which containing file Uploder I want to write JUnit for that. But its failing with following error.

> java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<406>
>       at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:55)
>       at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:82)
>       at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers.lambda$matcher$9(StatusResultMatchers.java:617)
>       at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:178)
>       at com.nokia.cem.ui.controllers.CgfDesignTest.SavePageConfigTest(CgfDesignTest.java:85)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(
       method = RequestMethod.PUT, 
       value = "/pageconfig/v1/{applicationName}/{usecaseName}", 
       consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, 
       produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> saveCGFConfiguration(
        @RequestHeader(value = CEMAppConstants.AUTHORIZATION) String token,
        @PathVariable String applicationName,
        @PathVariable String usecaseName,
        @RequestPart(CEMAppConstants.FILE) MultipartFile file)
        throws BeansException, IOException {

    commonService.isTokenAndApplicationNameValid(token, applicationName);

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK)
            .body(cgfPageconfigService.saveCgfPageconfig(applicationName, file, usecaseName));
}
```

Junit:

```
@Test
public void SavePageConfigTest() throws Exception {
    FileInputStream inputFile = new FileInputStream( "src/test/resource/umappedResponse.json");  
    MockMultipartFile file = new MockMultipartFile("file", "umappedResponse", "multipart/form-data", inputFile);


    when(cgfpageconfigService.saveCgfPageconfig(application, file, usecase))
            .thenReturn("{\"MESSAGE\":\"CGF pageConfig is saved successfully \"}");
    mockMvc.perform(put("/api/cgf/pageconfig/v1/"+application+"/"+usecase).accept(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
            .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE).header("Authorization", Auth))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().string("{\"MESSAGE\":\"CGF pageConfig is saved successfully \"}"));

}
```

Comment: I removed the Swagger annotations from your post. It's just unnecessary noise making the code harder to read.

Comment: A 406 means that you are requesting a data format (Accept header) that the server does not support (produces). You are sending a accept header of `multipart/form-data`, but the server produces `application/json`. You  change the accept header to `application/json` to get rid of the 406. You might still run into other problems though. Your test doesn't look quite right to me.

Comment: Example of testing file upload in spring boot : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51895861/spring-mvc-test-multipart-post-json-originalfilename-is-required/51898591#51898591

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.